# How do I create a SQLite query and embed it into an SQLite Database

Tags: sql, sqlite, embed

I am struggling to find an answer on how I can create a SQL query and embed it into an actual SQLite Database by my software.

OK, I am using a program language to create an SQLite database from scratch. This all works fine and has done for a few years. The software creates the database, then tables and then imports daily data. Once finished I will open the SQLite database in Navicat and then create/save the necessary SQL Queries, then I send the database to a non-technical collegue who will run the queries and do his job.

To save me loads of time I would like my program to create and embed the SQL queryies into the database at creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like CL. said, there is no way to embed queries into an SQLite DB you're opening outside of a program where it's integrated.

By why not just generate another file with your queries? Your buddy could run the queries from the file. As far as I see [here](http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/How_do_I_import_SQL_file_into_the_Server%3F), it shouldn't be  problem to do so in Navicat and it's probably just a text file or something similar which is easy to generate.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database; it is supposed to be integrated into some program that actually does something with the data.

If you want to access the database directly in Navicat, you could create a view for each of those queries.
This still requires you to execute something like

```
SELECT * FROM NaughtyOrNiceReport
```

in Navicat, but it's the best you can do.